# Jitter points in ggplot2 when the limits of the plot are fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I have a `ggplot` with fixed labels and fixed limits set in `scale_x_continuous`. Then there is a problem when I want to apply jitter:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(1, 2), 5),
  y = 1:10
)

gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_jitter(width = 0.5)
gg + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(dat$x), limits = c(1,2))
```

[image]

The problem is that the jittered points do not appear outside the limits. Is there a way to jitter the points so that the limits are updated? Or do I have to manually update the limits according to the jittering width?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the use case. If you want to adjust the plot limits based on the extent of geom elements in the plot, what's the purpose of setting limits in the first place?

Comment: @Z.Lin This is in the context of a Shiny app. The points are not jittered when the user uploads the data, but he can apply the jittering with a slider. The app is a bit complex.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could be addressed by applying the jitter before ggplot, in such a way that the post-jitter data could define your axis:

```
library(dplyr)
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(x2 = jitter(x, amount = 0.3))

ggplot(dat2, aes(x2,y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(dat2$x2), 
                     limits = range(dat2$x2))
```

[image]

Comment: Not a bad idea but I also use a vertical jittering. Hmm I see one could also apply the `jitter` function to `y`. Otherwise I had another idea: to extract the jittered values from `ggplot_build`. I don't know what's the best solution. +1 anyway. I also have facets in my plot, I don't know whether this brings up other complications.

Comment: Can you explain more what the intention is behind adding the `scale_x_continuous()` term? Another approach could be to change the way jitter is applied so that it does not extend the limits, e.g. `mutate(x2 = 0.8*x + 0.2*rnorm(10, 1.5, 0.2))`. That should pull the points inward toward the middle by varying amounts.

Comment: I add `scale_x_continuous` with fixed limits because I want the x-axis to cover all the points. Not sure I'm clear (I'm not always comfortable with English). I don't want to have a point not delimited by major lines.

Comment: When you leave out the `scale_x_continuous` line, what is different from what you want?

Comment: Imagine the vertical major lines are located at 10, 20 and 30. I can have a x located at 35, and I don't want that. So I add a major line at 40. Is it clearer ? I have solved the problem with `ggplot_build`.